# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibeststring.a

Tags: c++, ubuntu, festival

I am using festival TTS c++ API in my program.I have downloaded all files from http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/downloads/festival/2.0.95/
and install festival and speech_tools successfully on my UBUNTU 10.04

now when compile my c++ programme gcc gives error:

```
g++ -L/usr/lib -L/home/peeyush/Desktop/festival/src/lib -L/home/peeyush/Desktop/speech_tools/lib -o"peeyush" ./src/peeyush.o -llibeststring.a -llibestbase.a -llibestools.a -llibFestival.a
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibeststring.a
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [peeyush] Error 1
```

so please help me to sort out this error.

-Thanks

Peeyush Chandel(INDIA)

Comment: When you use "-l", it automatically prefixes library names with "lib".  So use -lbeststring -lbestbase etc instead

Answer (score 7):

When using the `-l` option, you don't specify the leading `lib` or trailing `.a` or `.so` parts of the name as they're assumed by the linker. You would want to use something like `-leststring` to pick it up (assuming that your `-L` path is set correctly.

Alternately you can specify the exact filename (so no `-l`, just `libeststring.a`) as part of the object list to link (make sure the order is right relative to your .o files), but I believe in that case you would have to specify the path as the linker won't know to search your `-L` path. Easiest is to use `-l` though.